# Play 2.0 'eclipsify' and 'netbeansify' command

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there a 'netbeansify' or 'elipsify' command in Play 2.0 like in the 1.x release of the Play framework? Is it planned? Or is there a manual way to start Play 2.0 form within Eclipse/NetBeans?

Comment: in the recent release it does support `eclipsify`, i haven't check for `netbeansify` though

Comment: As my current `Play` version(2.2.1) you can type the `eclipse` command instead of `eclipsify`. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/IDE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/IDE).

As per that link, `eclipsify` is still supported, however here is what it says about netbeans:

"Play does not have native Netbeans project generation support at this time. For now you can generate a Netbeans Scala project with the Netbeans SBT plugin"

Comment: I hope they add a native netbeans function in the near future!

Comment: Unfortunately, the Netbeans SBT plugin does not seem to work with Play 2.0 and Netbeans 7.1. It all runs, but Netbeans does not recognize it at a Netbeans project.

Comment: for me, netbeans recognizes it by using the play-netbeans plugin, but code completion doesn't work.